PowerShell return a custom error message on non-terminating error based on the error type
I have a PowerShell script that I am working on and I am trying to figure out how to have it catch the non-terminating error and return a custom error message instead of the standard error message text.  I am specifically concerned with 2 different errors that I expect to see based on parameters and how I can have the script return a custom error text depending on which error it is instead of returning the long system error.
Code is below
 $SG = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the Security Group you want to get the members for'
 $GPOType = Read-Host -Prompt 'Are you Linking a User or Computer GPO - Type either User or Computer'
 $gpoName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Group Policy Name you want to Link'
 $targetGpoName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Group Policy name of the policy that you want to link new one above - For example if the Target policy link order is 10 this will put the new Policy in Link Order 10 moving the target Polciy to Link Order 11'
 $EnableLink = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Yes or No to enable link or not'
 $GPO = get-gpo -Name $targetGpoName


 $OUlists = get-adgroupmember -identity $SG | where-object {$_.samaccountname -notlike '*svc*' -and $_.objectclass -like $GPOType} | ForEach-Object -process {
 $DN = $_.distinguishedname; 
 $null,$trailingRDNs = $DN -split '(?<!\\),'
 $parentDNs = $trailingRDNs -join ','

 foreach ($parentDN in $parentDNs)
 {

 Write-Host "Working on ($parentDN )"
 New-GPLink -Name $gpoName -order ((Get-GPInheritance -Target $parentDN).GpoLinks | Where-Object DisplayName -eq $targetGpoName | select -expandproperty order) -Target $parentDN -LinkEnabled $EnableLink 
 }
 }

the errors I am getting as expected are as follows:
first expected error:
when the target GPO isnt linked to the OU so the script cant determine the order since the target GPO isnt linked thus returning an error saying ...Cannot bind parameter 'Order' to the target. Exception setting "Order": "Cannot convert null...
this is expected and is the behavior i want for this but instead of returning the full error (as seen below) i want it to just return a custom message.  some thing like "GPO used for Order targeting is not linked to this OU.  New GPO will Not be linked to this OU"
full error:
New-GPLink : Cannot bind parameter 'Order' to the target. Exception setting "Order": "Cannot convert null to type "System.Int32"."
At line:23 char:36
Name -order ((Get-GPInheritance -Target $parentDN).GpoLinks | Where-O ...
CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-GPLink], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.NewGPLinkCommand
Second Error I am getting as expected is the error when the GPO is already linked to the desired OU.  again, this is an error I expect to get but also want a custom message to display something like this: "GPO is already linked to this OU"
the full error is below:
New-GPLink : The GPO named 'Test-Do-Not-Use' is already linked to a Scope of Management with Path
'OU=Blah,OU=Blah,DC=Something,DC=Somewhere,DC=Sometime,DC=Here,DC=There'.
At line:23 char:3
New-GPLink -Name $gpoName -order ((Get-GPInheritance -Target $paren ...
CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Group...ewGPLinkCommand:NewGPLinkCommand) [New-GPLink], ArgumentException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToCreateNewLink,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.NewGPLinkCommand
I have tried incorporating the write-error "custom statement" -category InvalidArgument or Write error depending on which error i am targeting and placed it inside the foreach loop under the New-Gplink section but that didnt get me anything.
since its a non-terminating error, i dont think i can use catch.
any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance
thanks to all for the help here is the working script
 $SG = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the Security Group you want to get the members for'
 $GPOType = Read-Host -Prompt 'Are you Linking a User or Computer GPO - Type either User or Computer'
 $gpoName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Group Policy Name you want to Link'
 $targetGpoName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Group Policy name of the policy that you want to link new one above - For example if the Target policy link order is 10 this will put the new Policy in Link Order 10 moving the target Polciy to Link Order 11'
 $EnableLink = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Yes or No to enable link or not'
 $GPO = get-gpo -Name $targetGpoName

 $OUlists = get-adgroupmember -identity $SG | where-object {$_.samaccountname -notlike '*svc*' -and $_.objectclass -like $GPOType} | ForEach-Object -process {
 $DN = $_.distinguishedname; 
 $null,$trailingRDNs = $DN -split '(?<!\\),'
 $parentDNs = $trailingRDNs -join ','

 foreach ($parentDN in $parentDNs){


 Write-Host "Working on ($parentDN )"
 try {
 New-GPLink -Name $gpoName -order ((Get-GPInheritance -Target $parentDN).GpoLinks | Where-Object DisplayName -eq $targetGpoName | select -expandproperty order) -Target $parentDN -LinkEnabled $EnableLink -ErrorAction Stop 
 }catch [System.ArgumentException]{
 write-warning "GPO is already linked to this OU"
 }
 catch [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException]{
 write-warning "Target GPO used for Order does not exist thus the GPO will not be linked"
 }
 }
 }


I commend to your attention Microsoft Learn on Try/Catch/Finally and Microsoft Learn on Common Parameters (and specifically -ErrorAction in the latter, which can (when used properly) allow you to convert a non-terminating error into a terminating error).

thank you, but i dont want to convert a non-terminating error into a terminating error.  i just want it to give a custom error message and then continue

That's one reason why you might indeed want to convert the non-terminating error into a terminating error - you can then use try/catch/finally catch the error, provide the custom message, then continue on. "Terminating error" just means that if you don't handle it, it will terminate the script. If you do handle it, you can continue after handling it.

You might find the example at LazyAdmin to be of interest.

reading more into now.  will see if i can make it work in the foreach loop.

@JeffZeitlin
so after finally getting the correct parameters from the error I was able to add them into the try / catch and it worked perfectly.  thank you for your help and educating me on the converting a non-terminating error into a terminating error to be able to use the try / catch.
i will provide the working full script by editing my question

You can run 'New-GPLink' with '-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err' and then see if there is an error to handle.
Here is an example code:
New-GPLink -Name $gpoName -order ((Get-GPInheritance -Target $parentDN).GpoLinks | Where-Object DisplayName -eq $targetGpoName | select -expandproperty order) -Target $parentDN -LinkEnabled $EnableLink -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err

if ($err.ToString() -like "*Cannot bind parameter 'Order' to the target*") {
    Write-Error -Message 'GPO used for Order targeting is not linked to this OU. New GPO will not be linked to this OU'
} elseif ($err.ToString() -like "*The GPO named 'Test-Do-Not-Use' is already linked to a Scope of Management with Path*") {
    Write-Error -Message 'GPO is already linked to this OU'
} else {
    Write-Error $err
}

By the way, something is confusing in your script. You are converting '$trailingRDNs' to a single string by running '$parentDNs = $trailingRDNs -join ','' and then you are running a foreach loop 'foreach ($parentDN in $parentDNs)' in '$parentDNs' which is a single string. Am I missing something?

the trailingDNs and split are part of what removes the computer, user or server name off the front of the distinguished name returned from the get-adgroupmember -identity $SG portion of the script.  then the parentDN is rejoining the information that trailingDN split so now we have just the distinguished name of the full OU without the user, computer or server name in front of it allowing the script to then target those OUs to link the GPOs

My confusion is why you use a foreach loop in a single string

its not a single string.
the $OUlists variable is created by get-adgroupmember -identity $SG ..... which contains a long list of computers or users distinguished names.
the the foreach-object -process {.....    runs and the uses the list of OUs splits them, removes the user or computer name from the OUs, joins them back together.  so now you have a long list of OUs minus the leading computer names or user names
then the foreach loop kicks in and uses the list of newly formed OUs and runs New-GPLink against the list of OUs

'foreach ($parentDN in $parentDNs)' is within the 'ForEach-Object -process {...' loop. In each cycle of the 'ForEach-Object' loop, '$parentDNs' is a single string. Therefore, there's no point in using a second foreach loop within the ForEach-Object loop.
It's not a problem for your script, and it will work well; it simply doesn't make sense to use a loop for a single string.

By the way, '$OUlists' doesn't contain the results of 'get-adgroupmember -identity $SG ....' Instead, 'get-adgroupmember -identity $SG ...' pipes its results to 'ForEach-Object' that calls New-GPLink. Therefore, the actual content of $OUlists is the output of 'New-GPLink'

you are correct about the $ParentDN.  cleaned it up and it works fine.  thanks for that advice.
